# Error: Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers (2054)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to migrate a number of websites built with and old version of CMS Made simple.

On the target server I have MySQL 8 setup and the websites obviously require PHP 5.6 to run.

When I try to launch the website, I am getting the below error message:

**Database Connection Failed

Error: Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers (2054)

Function Performed: CONNECT**

Any idea on how to resolve this please?

Thank you so much in advance!